# How to fix board game piece movement on processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm making a mini-monopoly board game for my CompSci class, and I need help with moving the pieces around the board. Each block is 90 pixels wide, and how much the pieces move is based on a dice roll. I don't know how to move the pieces around. I've pasted the code for the board down below.

I don't know whether I should put it in `void` `keyPressed()` or `voidDraw()` simply because the dice roll is based on a key press.

```
import java.util.Random;

void setup() {
    size (700,700);
    noLoop();
    background(205, 230, 208);

    // four squares on each corner
    strokeWeight(4);
    stroke(0);
    noFill();
    rect(0, 0, 125, 125);
    rect(575, 0, 125, 125);
    rect(0, 575, 125, 125);
    rect(575, 575, 125, 125);

    // squares top side
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == 2 || i == 3) {
            i=4;
        }

        rect(125 + (i * 90), 0, 90, 90);
    }
    // squares bottom side
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == 2) {
            i = 3;
        }

        rect(125 + (i * 90), 610, 90, 90);
    }
    // squares left side

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i == 1 || i == 2) {
            i = 3;
        }

        rect(0, 125 + (90 * i), 90, 90);
    }
    // squares right side
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (i==2 || i ==3){
            i = 4;
        }

        rect(610, 125 + (90 * i), 90, 90);
    }

    //inside square + lines for chance
    rect(125, 125, 450, 450);
    rect(0, 0, 700, 700); 

    line(0, 305, 125, 305);
    line(575, 395, 700, 395);
    line(305, 575, 305, 700);
    line(395, 0, 395, 125);

    // green
    fill(30, 178, 90);
    rect(125, 90, 90, 35); 
    rect(215, 90, 90, 35); 
    rect(485, 90, 90, 35); 

    // yellow
    fill(253, 241, 1);
    rect(90, 125, 35, 90); 
    rect(90, 395, 35, 90); 
    rect(90, 485, 35, 90);

    //red
    fill(224, 25, 33);
    rect(575, 125, 35, 90); 
    rect(575, 215, 35, 90); 
    rect(575, 485, 35, 90);

    // blue
    fill(172, 223, 252);
    rect(125, 575, 90, 35); 
    rect(395, 575, 90, 35); 
    rect(485, 575, 90, 35); 

    //logo
    PFont comic;
    PFont taxandchance = createFont("ComicSansMS", 75);
    fill (237, 27, 35); 
    comic = createFont("ComicSansMS", 45);
    textFont(comic);

    pushMatrix();
    translate(215, 490);
    rotate(radians(315));
    translate(-215, -490);
    text("Mini Monopoly TM", 215, 490);
    popMatrix();

    // go
    int x = 615;
    int y = 670;
    pushMatrix();
    fill(0);
    translate(x,y);
    rotate(radians(315));
    translate(-x, -y);
    text("GO", x, y);
    comic = createFont("ComicSansMS", 18);
    textFont(comic); 
    text("collect $200", x - 14, y + 25); 
    popMatrix();

    PFont corner = createFont("ComicSansMS", 35);
    // free parking
    x = 50;
    y = 100;
    pushMatrix();
    fill(0);
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(radians(315));
    translate(-x, -y);
    textFont(corner);
    text("Free", x, y);
    popMatrix();

    // stillwells
    x = 600;
    y = 40;
    pushMatrix();
    PFont stillwells = createFont("ComicSansMS", 25);
    textFont(stillwells);
    fill(0);
    translate(x,y);
    rotate(radians(45));
    translate(-x,-y);
    text("Stillwells", x, y);
    popMatrix();

    // grill
    x = 38;
    y = 620;
    pushMatrix();
    fill(0);
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(radians(45));
    translate(-x, -y);
    textFont(corner);
    text("Grill", x, y);
    popMatrix();

    // location names bottom row
    fill(0); 
    textFont(comic);
    text("Library", 500, 650);
    text("$100", 500, 680);
    text("Elm", 425, 650);
    text("$100", 418, 680);
    text("Weth", 145, 650);
    text("$120", 145, 680);
    text("Train", (325), 620);
    text("station:", (325), 640);
    text("Andover", (320), 660);
    textFont(taxandchance);
    fill(0, 175, 237);
    text("$", 236, 668);

    // location names top row

    x = 198;
    y = 55;
    pushMatrix();
    fill(0);
    textFont(comic);
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(radians(180));
    translate(-x, -y);
    text("Bowld", x, y);
    text("PHLH", x - 90, y);
    text("ACB", x - 350, y);
    text("$260", x, y + 30);
    text("$260", x - 90, y + 30);
    text("$280", x - 350, y + 30);
    text("Train", x - 182, y - 25);
    text("station:", x - 189, y - 5);
    text("Hotchkiss", x - 195, y + 25);
    textFont(taxandchance);
    fill(0, 175, 237);
    text("$", x - 261, y + 20);

    popMatrix();

    // locationnames yellow
    x = 60;
    y = 511;
    pushMatrix();
    textFont(comic);
    fill(0);
    translate(x, y);
    rotate(radians(90));
    translate(-x, -y);
    text("HR", x, y);
    text("OMA", x - 90, y);
    text("Bissell", x -364, y);
    text("$180", x, y + 30);
    text("$180", x - 90, y + 30);
    text("$200", x - 360, y + 30);
    text("Train", x - 182, y - 25);
    text("station:", x - 189, y - 5);
    text("Choate", x - 186, y + 25);
    textFont(taxandchance);
    fill(247, 134, 32);
    text("?", x - 270, y + 25); 
    popMatrix();

    // locationnames red
    x = 640;
    y = 190;
    pushMatrix();
    textFont(comic);
    fill(0);
    translate(x,y);
    rotate(radians(270));
    translate(-x, -y);
    text("Phelps", x - 5, y);
    text("Field H.", x - 100, y);
    text("Goel", x - 363, y);
    text("$320", x, y + 30);
    text("$350", x - 90, y + 30);
    text("$400", x - 370, y + 30);
    text("Train", x - 182, y - 25);
    text("station:", x - 189, y - 5);
    text("Deerfield:", x - 200, y + 25);

    textFont(taxandchance);
    fill(247, 134, 32);
    text("?", x - 270, y + 25);
    popMatrix();

    // tokens
    fill(226, 53, 143); 
    ellipse(630, 630, 30, 30);
    fill(1, 110, 203); 
    ellipse(630, 665, 30, 30);
    println(name1 + " press 'l' to roll!"); 

}

int p1position = 0; 
int p2position = 0; 
int p1diceroll;
int p2diceroll;
String name1 = "Jasmine";
String name2 = "Iliana"; 


void keyPressed() {
    noLoop(); 

    Random rand = new Random();

    if (key == 'l') {
        // Obtain a number between [0 - 5].
        p1diceroll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        println("You rolled a " + p1diceroll + "!"); 
        println(name2 + " press 'a' to roll");
    }

    if (key == 'a') {

        // Obtain a number between [0 - 5].
        p2diceroll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        println("You rolled a " + p2diceroll + "!");  

        if (p1diceroll > p2diceroll){
            System.out.println(name1 + " rolled higher!. They go first.");
        }

        if (p2diceroll > p1diceroll) {
            System.out.println(name2 + " rolled higher!. They go first. "); 
        }

        if (p2diceroll == p1diceroll) {
            System.out.println("It's a tie! " + name1 + " goes first by default." ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one big class to debug. Modularize the code and break into smaller classes with distinct responsibility. It will easier for you and us to understand and debug.

Comment: Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm). It is a pretty useful way to solve complex problems, like your class. Also (if you have time of course) you can look at junit to test your methods and guarantee that your methods work. Edit: a good programming style is to have atomic functions, and you are supposed to be able to use your methods without understanding them (like a remote, you can turn on your tv without understanding how it works)

Comment: I've only been coding for a couple of weeks and I've just started using processing 3 days ago, so I have no clue what debugging / Modularisation means. thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create list of all fields. Use (e.g.) [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) tor store the rectangles of the fields in a dynamic array:

e.g.

```java
ArrayList<int[]> fields = new ArrayList<int[]>();

void setup() {

    // bottom right
    fields.add(new int[]{575, 575, 125, 125});

    // squares bottom side
    for (int i=4; i>=0; i--){
        fields.add(new int[]{125+(i*90), (i==1 || i==2) ? 575 : 610, 90, (i==1 || i==2) ? 125 : 90});
    }

    // bottom left
    fields.add(new int[]{0, 575, 125, 125});

    // squares left side
    for (int i=4; i>=0; i--){
        fields.add(new int[]{0, 125+(90*i), (i==1 || i==2) ? 125 : 90, 90});
    }

    // top left
    fields.add(new int[]{0, 0, 125, 125});

    // squares top side
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
       fields.add(new int[]{125+(i*90), 0, 90, (i==2 || i==3) ? 125 : 90});
    }

    // top right
    fields.add(new int[]{575, 0, 125, 125});

    // squares right side
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        fields.add(new int[]{(i==2 || i ==3) ? 575 : 610, 125+(90*i), (i==2 || i ==3) ? 125 : 90, 90});
    }

    // [...]

}
```

Draw the entire board to a [`PGraphics`](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) object:

```java
PGraphics board;

void setup() {

    // [...]

    size(700, 700);  
    board = createGraphics(700, 700);
    board.beginDraw();

    board.background(205,230,208);

    // four squares on each corner
    board.strokeWeight(4);
    board.stroke(0);
    board.noFill();

    for(int[] f : fields) {
        board.rect(f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3]);
    }   

    // [...]

    board.endDraw();
}
```

Now you can use the Processing game loop. Draw the board to the window ([`image`](https://processing.org/reference/image_.html)) and draw the players on top of the board, on its individual positions:

```java
int pos_l = 0;
int pos_a = 0;

void draw() {
    image(board, 0, 0); 

    // tokens

    int xl = fields.get(pos_l)[0] + fields.get(pos_l)[2] / 3;
    int yl = fields.get(pos_l)[1] + fields.get(pos_l)[3] / 3;
    fill(226, 53, 143); 
    ellipse(xl, yl, 30, 30);

    int xa = fields.get(pos_a)[0] + fields.get(pos_a)[2] * 2 / 3;
    int ya = fields.get(pos_a)[1] + fields.get(pos_a)[3] * 2 / 3;
    fill(1, 110, 203); 
    ellipse(xa, ya, 30, 30);  
}
```

In the `keyPressed` event you've to implement the game logic and to chang the position of the players (`player_l`, `player_a`):

```java
void keyPressed() {

    Random rand = new Random();

    if (key == 'l'){
        // Obtain a number between [0 - 5].
        p1diceroll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

        // [...]

        pos_l = (pos_l + p1diceroll) % fields.size();
    }

    if (key == 'a'){

        // Obtain a number between [0 - 5].
        p2diceroll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;

        // [...]        

        pos_a = (pos_a + p2diceroll) % fields.size();
    }
}
```

See the example, where I applied the the suggestions to the code of the question. The example doesn't provide any game logic, it just adds the dice to the positions of the players and moves the players around the board:

[image]

```java
import java.util.Random;

ArrayList<int[]> fields = new ArrayList<int[]>();

PGraphics board;

void setup()
{
    // bottom right
    fields.add(new int[]{575, 575, 125, 125});

    // squares bottom side
    for (int i=4; i>=0; i--){
        fields.add(new int[]{125+(i*90), (i==1 || i==2) ? 575 : 610, 90, (i==1 || i==2) ? 125 : 90});
    }

    // bottom left
    fields.add(new int[]{0, 575, 125, 125});

    // squares left side
    for (int i=4; i>=0; i--){
        fields.add(new int[]{0, 125+(90*i), (i==1 || i==2) ? 125 : 90, 90});
    }

    // top left
    fields.add(new int[]{0, 0, 125, 125});

    // squares top side
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
       fields.add(new int[]{125+(i*90), 0, 90, (i==2 || i==3) ? 125 : 90});
    }

    // top right
    fields.add(new int[]{575, 0, 125, 125});

    // squares right side
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
        fields.add(new int[]{(i==2 || i ==3) ? 575 : 610, 125+(90*i), (i==2 || i ==3) ? 125 : 90, 90});
    }


    size(700, 700);  
    board = createGraphics(700, 700);
    board.beginDraw();

    board.background(205,230,208);

    // four squares on each corner
    board.strokeWeight(4);
    board.stroke(0);
    board.noFill();

    for(int[] f : fields) {
        board.rect(f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3]);
    }   

    //inside square + lines for chance
    board.rect(125, 125, 450, 450);
    board.rect(0, 0, 700, 700); 

    board.line(0, 305, 125, 305);
    board.line(575, 395, 700, 395);
    board.line(305, 575, 305, 700);
    board.line(395, 0, 395, 125);

    // green
    board.fill(30, 178, 90);
    board.rect(125, 90, 90, 35); 
    board.rect(215, 90, 90, 35); 
    board.rect(485, 90, 90, 35); 

    // yellow
    board.fill(253, 241, 1);
    board.rect(90, 125, 35, 90); 
    board.rect(90, 395, 35, 90); 
    board.rect(90, 485, 35, 90);

    //red
    board.fill(224, 25, 33);
    board.rect(575, 125, 35, 90); 
    board.rect(575, 215, 35, 90); 
    board.rect(575, 485, 35, 90);

    // blue
    board.fill(172, 223, 252);
    board.rect(125, 575, 90, 35); 
    board.rect(395, 575, 90, 35); 
    board.rect(485, 575, 90, 35); 

    //logo
    PFont comic;
    PFont taxandchance = createFont("ComicSansMS", 75);
    board.fill (237, 27, 35); 
    comic = createFont("ComicSansMS", 45);
    board.textFont(comic);

    board.pushMatrix();
    board.translate(215,490);
    board.rotate(radians(315));
    board.translate(-215,-490);
    board.text("Mini Monopoly TM", 215, 490);
    board.popMatrix();

    // go
    int x = 615;
    int y = 670;
    board.pushMatrix();
    board.fill(0);
    board.translate(x,y);
    board.rotate(radians(315));
    board.translate(-x,-y);
    board.text("GO", x, y);
    comic = createFont("ComicSansMS", 18);
    board.textFont(comic); 
    board.text("collect $200", x-14, y+25); 
    board.popMatrix();

    PFont corner = createFont("ComicSansMS", 35);
    // free parking
    x = 50;
    y = 100;
    board.pushMatrix();
    board.fill(0);
    board.translate(x,y);
    board.rotate(radians(315));
    board.translate(-x,-y);
    board.textFont(corner);
    board.text("Free", x, y);
    board.popMatrix();

    // stillwells
    x = 600;
    y = 40;
    board.pushMatrix();
    PFont stillwells = createFont("ComicSansMS", 25);
    board.textFont(stillwells);
    board.fill(0);
    board.translate(x,y);
    board.rotate(radians(45));
    board.translate(-x,-y);
    board.text("Stillwells", x, y);
    board.popMatrix();

    // grill
    x = 38;
    y = 620;
    board.pushMatrix();
    board.fill(0);
    board.translate(x,y);
    board.rotate(radians(45));
    board.translate(-x,-y);
    board.textFont(corner);
    board.text("Grill", x, y);
    board.popMatrix();

    // location names bottom row
    board.fill (0); 
    board.textFont(comic);
    board.text("Library", 500, 650);
    board.text("$100", 500, 680);
    board.text("Elm", 425, 650);
    board.text("$100", 418, 680);
    board.text("Weth", 145, 650);
    board.text("$120", 145, 680);
    board.text("Train", (325), 620);
    board.text("station:", (325), 640);
    board.text("Andover", (320), 660);
    board.textFont(taxandchance);
    board.fill(0, 175,237);
    board.text("$", 236, 668);

    // location names top row

    x = 198;
    y = 55;
    board.pushMatrix();
    board.fill(0);
    board.textFont(comic);
    board.translate(x,y);
    board.rotate(radians(180));
    board.translate(-x,-y);
    board.text("Bowld", x, y);
    board.text("PHLH", x - 90, y);
    board.text("ACB", x - 350, y);
    board.text("$260", x, y+30);
    board.text("$260", x - 90, y+30);
    board.text("$280", x - 350, y+30);
    board.text("Train", x - 182, y-25);
    board.text("station:", x - 189, y-5);
    board.text("Hotchkiss", x - 195, y+25);
    board.textFont(taxandchance);
    board.fill(0, 175,237);
    board.text("$", x-261, y+20);

    board.popMatrix();

    // locationnames yellow
    x = 60;
    y = 511;
    board.pushMatrix();
    board.textFont(comic);
    board.fill(0);
    board.translate(x,y);
    board.rotate(radians(90));
    board.translate(-x,-y);
    board.text("HR", x, y);
    board.text("OMA", x - 90, y);
    board.text("Bissell", x -364, y);
    board.text("$180", x, y+30);
    board.text("$180", x - 90, y+30);
    board.text("$200", x - 360, y+30);
    board.text("Train", x - 182, y-25);
    board.text("station:", x - 189, y-5);
    board.text("Choate", x - 186, y+25);
    board.textFont(taxandchance);
    board.fill(247,134,32);
    board.text("?", x-270, y+25); 
    board.popMatrix();

    // locationnames red
    x = 640;
    y = 190;
    board.pushMatrix();
    board.textFont(comic);
    board.fill(0);
    board.translate(x,y);
    board.rotate(radians(270));
    board.translate(-x,-y);
    board.text("Phelps", x-5, y);
    board.text("Field H.", x - 100, y);
    board.text("Goel", x -363, y);
    board.text("$320", x, y+30);
    board.text("$350", x - 90, y+30);
    board.text("$400", x - 370, y+30);
    board.text("Train", x - 182, y-25);
    board.text("station:", x - 189, y-5);
    board.text("Deerfield:", x - 200, y+25);

    board.textFont(taxandchance);
    board.fill(247,134,32);
    board.text("?", x-270, y+25);
    board.popMatrix();

    board.endDraw();
}

int pos_l = 0;
int pos_a = 0;

void draw(){
    image(board, 0, 0); 

    // tokens

    int xl = fields.get(pos_l)[0] + fields.get(pos_l)[2] / 3;
    int yl = fields.get(pos_l)[1] + fields.get(pos_l)[3] / 3;
    fill(226, 53, 143); 
    ellipse(xl, yl, 30, 30);

    int xa = fields.get(pos_a)[0] + fields.get(pos_a)[2] * 2 / 3;
    int ya = fields.get(pos_a)[1] + fields.get(pos_a)[3] * 2 / 3;
    fill(1, 110, 203); 
    ellipse(xa, ya, 30, 30);  
}

int p1position = 0; 
int p2position = 0; 
int p1diceroll;
int p2diceroll;
String name1 = "Jasmine";
String name2 = "Iliana"; 

void keyPressed(){

    Random rand = new Random();

    if (key == 'l'){
        // Obtain a number between [0 - 5].
        p1diceroll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        println("You rolled a " + p1diceroll + "!"); 
        println(name2 + " press 'a' to roll");

        pos_l = (pos_l + p1diceroll) % fields.size();
    }

    if (key == 'a'){

        // Obtain a number between [0 - 5].
        p2diceroll = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
        println("You rolled a " + p2diceroll + "!");  
        if (p1diceroll>p2diceroll){
            System.out.println(name1 + " rolled higher!. They go first.");
        }
        if (p2diceroll>p1diceroll){
            System.out.println(name2 + " rolled higher!. They go first. "); 
        }
        if (p2diceroll==p1diceroll){
            System.out.println("It's a tie! " + name1 + " goes first by default." ); 
        }

        pos_a = (pos_a + p2diceroll) % fields.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: "We learn more by looking for the answer to a question and not finding it than we do from learning the answer itself."

Comment: @DavidS I not sure if I understand what you want to tell me.

Comment: Thank you so so so much!

Comment: @Rabbid76 he's telling you that writing his homework for him teaches him nothing.

Comment: @AntoineB Man the code is well explain, with links to the resources.

Comment: Yes, and the person asking the question will copy the code without looking at anything else.

Comment: @Rabbid76 very nice answer. OP did his best and was stuck, and you explained every step on how to do it. There are not many answers like this.